# Should I model a retryable property in my custom exception

Tags: java, c#, exception

I am creating some custom exceptions and would like to know if I should model a isRetryable property in the exception? It's upto the client whether he wants to retry or not even if that property is set to true.

For example, exceptions like NetworkConnectionInterruptedException, HttpTimeoutException, StaleConnectionException are something which a client can retry, if he wish to.

However exceptions like UnknownUserException, InvalidAccountState etc. should never be attempted to retry by the client.

So does it make sense to include this property and set to true in former case and false in later case? (Examples as below)

```
public class NetworkConnectionInterruptedException extends Exception {
public boolean isRetryable() {
return true;
}
}
public class UnknownUserException extends Exception {
public boolean isRetryable() {
return false;
}
}
```

The main intention is just letting user know that he can retry if he wish to, though not mandated - An alternative way to let him know along with manual documentation in the API.

I haven't seen this being used anywhere in java world, so not sure if that's the right way to go.

Please provide views on this.

Comment: Is this a C# question or a Java question?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...and yes what you describe is a good pattern, let the caller decide when to quit.

```
   public class MyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var OKToStop = false;
            var list = new List<OfSomething>();
            list.RepeatUntil(data =>
            {
                OKToStop = data.Count > 200;
                return OKToStop;
            },exception => {

                OKToStop = true;
                LogException(exception);

            });
        }

        private void LogException(Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And this to support code above...

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static List<OfSomething> RepeatUntil(this List<OfSomething> list, Func<List<OfSomething>, bool> Until, Action<Exception> Error)
        {
            try {
            var ok = Until(list);
            while (!ok){
                list = GetNewData();
                ok = Until(list);
            }
            }
            catch (Exception iox) {
                Error(iox);
            }
            return list;

        }

        private static List<OfSomething> GetNewData()
        {
            //Add new data or get new data or change something
            return RefreshData();
        }

        private static List<OfSomething> RefreshData()
        {
            //get  data from DB here etc.

        }
    }
```

Comment: My question is more regarding whether it's good practice to add isRetryable() method in exception class. Updated my question with sample classes having the method to make it more clear.